# Gmaps v3 Change style of MapTypeControlStyle DROPDOWN_MENU

Tags: jquery, prototype, google-maps-api-3

Can someone help me to change the style of MapTypeControl DROPDOWN_MENU without needing to build a complete new one. I searching to preserve localisations using the Default dropdown in place to build my own not localised when load.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setOptions` method on the [Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) object to accomplish what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
      },
      navigationControl: true,
      navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);  


    $('#link-drop-down').click(function() {
      map.setOptions({
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        }
      });
    });

    $('#link-hbar').click(function() {
      map.setOptions({
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR 
        }
      });
    });
  });  
</script>


</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <a id="link-drop-down" href="#">Change to Drop Down Menu</a>
  <a id="link-hbar" href="#">Change to Horizontal Bar</a>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry i talk about style css of this dropdown and not changing one type to another. my question it's not clearly i apologize. I search to modify this defaut selector addind left and right div and background img.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. Can you provide some code or an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to change the look of the drop down menu. That is not possible with the API and if you want a different looking drop down menu then you will need to write your own custom control, you can read more on the docs http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls